# iOS8 animation code does not work anymore

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, ios8

The code I used to animate a UITextField worked for me until XCode Version 6.0 (6A215l). Now XCode6 Beta7 not reposition UITextField. What should I do to make it work? 
Here the code:

```
@interface TableConfigViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField                   *customTableName;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.customTableName setDelegate:self];
}
- (void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField
                      up:(BOOL)up
{
    const float movementDuration = 0.5f;
    const int movementDistance = 380;
    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:movementDuration];
    self.customTableName.frame = CGRectOffset(self.customTableName.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the source of your problem but you should consider using the block based APIs (available since iOS 4.0) for UIView animations.

From Apple's docs regarding `beginAnimations:context:`

**"Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead."**

For example (untested):

```
- (void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField
                      up:(BOOL)up
{
    const float movementDuration = 0.5f;
    const int movementDistance = 380;
    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:movementDuration
                     animations:
                     ^{
                         self.customTableName.frame = CGRectOffset(self.customTableName.frame, 0, movement);
                     }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @WorkingDev, I used the blocks as Apple's docs suggested but still not working

Comment: Tried the 'block' solution and still not working on iOS 8 (works fine on iOS 7.x).